# Google Sheets Add-on rejected with no reason

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

We've developed a Google Sheets add-on and I saw the status as 'UnPublished (Rejected)' about 2 weeks after submission and we got no email or any other information about why this add-on has been rejected.

*Note: We've got the OAuth approved & published.*

What should be done to publish the Google Sheets add-on in the GSuite marketplace to the public?

Which Google team should we contact to get to know issue?

Comment: Did you find the reason why it was rejected? Facing the same issue.